# Prevent 'not-null property references a null or transient value'

Tags: nhibernate

I have mapping

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" assembly="DatabaseAccess" namespace="DatabaseAccess.poco">
  <class name="Employee" table="emplyees" lazy="true">
    <id name="id">
      <generator class="increment"></generator>
    </id>

    <property name="first_name" not-null="true"></property>
    <property name="last_name" not-null="true"></property>
    <property name="login" not-null="true"></property>
    <property name="sid"></property> 

  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

What I can do if session.Save(object) do not throw exception:
`not-null property references a null or transient value`
I want to fill these nulls before commit anyway.

Comment: Well, why you don't fill it before calling `Save`?

Comment: -"Doctor, it hurts when I do this" -"Then stop doing it"

Comment: @DiegoMijelshon. +10 if I could.

Answer (score 1):

> What I can do if session.Save(object) do not throw exception: not-null property references a null or transient value I want to fill these nulls before commit anyway.

- Change the mapping to be not nullable.
- fill those null before saving.
- update the saved entity:

---

```
 session.Save(obj);
 obj.Foo = new foo();

//session.SaveOrUpdate(object) // required if it's a new session.
```